# html2canvas does not render the canvas element of my page

Tags: javascript, pdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I am trying to create a pdf, containing an image of my application screen containing a canvas element, that you can work with.

Every time I print the screen, the canvas looks blank, for example and I also have a map, which is loaded on the page itself from an iframe and is not visible either.

My code is the following

```
contenedorCanvas = document.querySelector("#contenting");
       html2canvas(document.body) // Llamar a html2canvas y pasarle el elemento
.then(htmltwocanvas => {
      contenedorCanvas.appendChild(htmltwocanvas); // Lo agregamos como hijo del div
    });
```

The image I get is the application's own interface, with the canvas in the center, but it is blank, without content

[image]

**Edit**
In this image I can see part of the canvas, but not all the content of the canvas. The blue box is an element generated within the canvas, and in this case it can be seen. Why don't the other elements of the canvas?
[image]

Comment: From `html2canvas` docs: "All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy. Similarly, if you have other canvas elements on the page, which have been tainted with cross-origin content, they will become dirty and no longer readable by html2canvas. The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java applets." Not sure if related.

Comment: It is possible, but not entirely, I am doing tests, and I can generate an element of the canvas, which I know is inside the canvas, and it is rendered in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try `contenedorCanvas = document.getElementById("contenting");` intead of querySelector